# Java plist parsing: how to determine if an NSObject is an array or a dictionary

Tags: java, plist

I am using [a Java library for parsing plist files](https://code.google.com/p/plist/).

This is how you parse a file:

```
File file = new File("Info.plist");
NSDictionary rootDict = (NSDictionary)PropertyListParser.parse(file);
```

As you can see, the `parse` method returns an `NSObject` object, which you cast to `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` depending on what you're working with.

But what if I *don't know* whether the root is a dictionary or an array? Given an `NSObject` instance, how can I tell what does it represent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `instanceof` operator.

```
if (myObject instanceof NSArray) {
    //do something
} else if (myObject instanceof NSDictionary) {
    //do another thing
} else {
    // (myObject instanceof NSObject) another subclass of NSObject
}
```